# Add different layout of infoWindow to marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, infowindow

I have a couple of markers on my map. To each one of them, I want to inflate a custom infoWindow.

The problem i'm having is that the infoWindow is the same for each one. I have read a couple of stack threads but I haven't figured out how to fix it.

**Snippet where I add the markers to the map**

```
        for (int i = 0; i<cityObjects.size(); i++){
            CityObject cObject = cityObjects.get(i);
            Coordinates loc = cObject.getCoordinates();
            LatLng pos = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(cObject.getName()));
            loadInfoWindow(cObject.getImgs().get(0), cObject.getName());

            builder.include(pos);
        }
```

**Method to inflate the custom infoWindow**

```
    public void loadInfoWindow(final String url, final CharSequence title) {
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {


            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                arg0.getId();
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_info_window, null);
                Button info = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
                info.setText(title);
                BitmapLayout back = (BitmapLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.bitmapBackground);
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(back);

                return v;

            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

                return null;
            }
        });

    }
```

I read something about `setInfoWindowAdapter` being a setter and therefore overrides the infoWindow each time the for-loop iterates. Does anyone have a good solution on how to recognize the markers so I can inflate different layouts?

Comment: You have lat long for each marker, So on marker click you can generate your layout by comparing your marker lat long.

Comment: @chetanprajapat Great, it works! Big thanks

Comment: always welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid for not seeing this but I managed to write a solution.
Thanks to @chetanprajapat for getting me on the right track.

Since I have all information about the marker(location, title), I can just pass that into a created class which will check for the title and then inflate the proper layout.

**Created class for inflating the correct layout**

```
    public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter{
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

                for (CityObject cityObject : cityObjects){
                    if (arg0.getTitle().equals(cityObject.getName())){
                        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_info_window, null);
                        Button info = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
                        info.setText(cityObject.getName());
                        BitmapLayout back = (BitmapLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.bitmapBackground);
                        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(cityObject.getImgs().get(0)).into(back);
                        return v;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

                return null;
            }
    }
```

And then I just set the adapter to a new `Instance` of `CustomInfoWindowAdapter`

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
```

Again, thanks to @chetanprajapat for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marker.setTag() and marker.getTag(). You can give a tag to marker.for example

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(cObject.getName())).setTag(1);

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(cObject.getName())).setTag(2);
```

and then in loadInfoWindow method

```
   if((int)arg0.getTag==1)
  {
  //do something
  }
 else{
 //do something
 }
```